# General JavaScript Syntax Question

Tags: javascript, syntax

In the following code, why are both of the methods (increment and print) listed inside of return? Why can't you just use `return counter++`? Also, what does it mean to return a `console.log`?

```
function create() {
  var counter = 0;
  return {
    increment: function() {
      counter++;
    },
    print: function() {
      console.log(counter);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The code would be more readable with the missing semi-colon

Comment: @Šime Vidas This code would be just as readable with no semi-colons, if it remains formatted nicely over lines (as it is now) :-) (And it would be as un-readable with semi-colons if it was messy and scrunched up...)

Comment: You *could* use `return counter++`, imagine: `x = create(); console.log(x.increment())`. However, the first value will be 0 because the ++ "happens-after" the current value of the variable is evaluated in the expression.

Comment: @pst I disagree. My remark is a tiny detail, but it still would make a difference regarding readability. The second ending brace would be followed by a semi-colon - `};` - and that would indicate that a statement ends at that point in code. This additional piece of information makes it more readable.

Comment: @Šime Vidas It adds no "improvement" for me above the acceptably clean indentation levels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What this returns is more or less a Counter, if we rename the topmost function, it should make more sense.

Well what does it do? Let's add some comments

```
function Counter() { // a function, nothing special here
  var counter = 0; // a variable that's local to the function Counter
  return { // return an object literal {}
    // which has a property named 'increment'
    increment: function() { // that's a function AND a closure
      counter++; // and therefore still has access to the variable 'counter' inside of Counter
    },
    print: function() { // another function
      console.log(counter); // this logs to the console in most web browser
                            // the console object was introduces by Firebug 
                            // and effort is made being to standardize it
    }
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var a = Counter(); // you don't need the new keyword here sinc in this case
                   // there's no difference because the implicit return overwrites
                   // the normal constructor behavior of returning 'this'
a.increment();
a.print(); // 1
var b = Counter();
b.print(); // 0
```

Note the variable `counter` inside the function is not accessible from the outside, therefore it's **readonly**, an effect you can only achieve by using a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-does-a-javascript-closure-work).

Answer (score 4):

This code returns an object that contains two methods.

It uses a feature called an object literal:

```
var sampleObject = { someProperty: 3, otherProperty: "Hi there!" };
```

In this case, the properties are function literals.

Comment: You missed like half of the things that are going on there :/

Answer (score 3):

The `create` function returns an object that contains two methods - `increment` and `print`.

Every time you call the `create` function, a new object will be returned. This means that you can have multiple "counters" at the same time.

```
var counter1 = create();
var counter2 = create();

counter1.increment();
counter1.print(); // prints 1

counter2.print(); // prints 0
```

---

Btw, the local variable `counter` of the `create` function is bound to the `increment` and `print` methods through a closure. Read about closures here: http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/

Comment: Put in an explanation of the closure bit and I'll give a vote ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The code you suggest:

```
function create() {
  var counter = 0;
  return counter++;
}
```

would have a different effect.  That would return 0, then increment `counter` (which would then go out of scope).

The actual code returns a object (created with a object literal, as noted by SLaks).  The object has two methods, `increment` and `print`.  The increment method increments `counter` (it does not return it).  `print` prints it using `console.log`.

The reason this works is that `counter` is closed into both methods of the object literal.  This roughly means it stays alive, and is added to those methods' scopes.  Closures are a commonly used and important feature of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The increment operator `++` when following a return would essentially be working retroactively. So if your variable value was 5 and you return it following by `++`, you would return 5.

`console.log()` is typically used to debug things. It outputs the value of counter in this case to the console.